# Python: Classes/sub-classes and inheritance/determining sub-class

Tags: python-2.7, class, subclass

So I've been trying to understand classes, sub-classes, instantiation, and all
that good stuff. I've been trying to write a simple-ish code similar to a
more complicated code I saw (or at least it was hard for me to follow), but
I'm having trouble connecting all the pieces.

Here's what I want to happen.

We have a class Hotel. When you come into the hotel you have a name and a room
number. The number of your room determines what floor you are on.

```
class Hotel(object):

    def __init__(self, name, room_number):
        self.name = name
        self.room_number = room_number
        self.floor = self.room_number//10
```

So

```
Abe = Hotel("Abe", 104)
print "%s is in room %d on floor %d." % (Abe.name,
                                         Abe.room_number,
                                         Abe.floor)
```

## Abe is in room 104 on floor 1.

```
Bob = Hotel("Bob", 225)
print "%s is in room %d on floor %d." % (Bob.name,
                                         Bob.room_number,
                                         Bob.floor)
```

## Bob is in room 225 on floor 2.

And I want the first and second floors to be subclasses of Hotel.
The Fisrtst floor would have a vending machine and the second would have 
a computer lobby.

```
class FirstFloor(Hotel):
    # Something should go here?

    def vending_machine(): # something inside the ()?
        print "You buy a soda and feel refreshed."


class SecondFloor(Hotel):
    # Something should go here?

    def computer_lobby(): # something inside the ()?
        print "You have learned to write python!"
```

What would I have to add so that the room number the person is put in determines whether he can use the vending machines or the computer lobby?

Sorry if something doesn't look quite right, I'm rather new to this and this is my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: Inheritance is an "is a" relationship. In your design, does it make sense to say "The third floor is a hotel" - not really. Your hotel is tracking how many floors it has... so how many floors does the third floor have? You should also abstract the floor. Right now you have to duplicate the class for each floor when you likely want a single "Floor" class and you put multiple of them in a list or dict in the "Hotel" class. Then you can sensibly say "my hotel has floors".

Comment: I see. That makes sense. So if I do it like that, how would I give each floor its unique feature that you cant access from other floors?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're struggling to understand how to apply inheritance to the design you show because it doesn't make much sense. A `Hotel` is not the same thing as a room in a hotel, but your current `Hotel` class has attributes related to a person in a single room.

If you want a class with those attributes, you should probably make it a `Room` class with instances for each room, or maybe a `Guest` class for the person staying in a room. A `floor` could be a container (like a list) holding several rooms. Or maybe there should be a `Floor` class that contains a list of rooms as well as some additional data and methods.

It might also be better if `FirstFloor` and `SecondFloor` were not separate classes but instead instances of the same class with different data. It is often a sign you don't really need to write a class if there will only ever be a single instance of it!

Using a single class for all floors does limit your ability to add an extra methods to just a single floor. But think about when you'd be able to call such a method. If just one floor has a `computer_lobby` method, could you ever call `some_floor.computer_lobby()` when you don't know ahead of time which type of object the variable `some_floor` contains? Probably not, since it will fail if it was any floor but the second.

A more sensible design would be to make the "special" stuff about each floor data rather than methods. Maybe the `ComputerLobby` is a special subclass of `Room`, which can be contained in a list in an instance of the `Floor` class.